# How to stop URI from being encoding the reserved characters when executing?

Tags: java, android, json, uri

I'm Trying to do an android app which contains an URI of a JSON file . The JSON File URI contains some reserved characters in the link and hence when executing, the link is being automatically replaced with the encoded form of those characters. therefore Im not being able to retrieve the JSON file from the link.

The link when entered in Browser shows output but through program it does not show.The link after encoding when entered in a browser show nothing but  a blank page.

- Sorry I Cant post the Link here...( Characters which are shown in the URI are {?,_ etc..} present in the link of the file.
  How shall I COUNTER this problem?
  (How to use the Escape characters to resolve this problem?)

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: Can you at least share the part of the URL that's causing trouble?